How to download GitHub release asset when fetched via GraphQL API
I have already seen a couple of threads on how to download a release asset from a GitHub private repo here.
My use case is slightly different, I believe.
My first attempt was to fetch the release asset ID via the GraphQL API. It returns something like this:
{
  "data": {
    "repository": {
      "release": {
        "releaseAssets": {
          "nodes": [
            {
              "id": "RA_kwDOLPHDFs4LAY_P",
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Now, the GitHub REST API expects an asset_id as integer though. No way of changing the string value to the expected integer, or is there?
Then I decided to load the assetDownloadUrl via GraphQL instead and use the authenticated GitHub client to download it. This doesn't work either and returns 404.
I am using Golang and a mix of both the REST API (https://github.com/google/go-github) and GrahpQL API (https://github.com/shurcooL/githubv4). I prefer the GraphQL API, because I can wrap at least two requests into one.
Is there any way to make this work?

I believe you shoud go for the url there, with a query like:
query {
  repository(owner: "<owner>", name: "<repo>")
  {
    releases(first: 1) {
      nodes {
        releaseAssets(first: 20) {
          nodes {
            url
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

The url should lead to something like https://objects.githubusercontent.com/... which - I believe - accepts the usual API authentication with an access token. The other downloadUrl works only in a browser session.
The id you're writing about is very likely the node_id in the REST API response, but as you say, that's not applicable in the REST API call for getting an asset. you should be fine with the URL, though.
